# undefined method `og_action!' for facebook open graph (ROR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-opengraph, fb-graph

I am developing small web application in which I want to implement facebook open graph actions. so my code looks like

```
begin
      @auth_fb = user_token
      @app = ENV['FB_KEY']
      me = @auth_fb.token

      action = me.og_action!(
        "og_follows",
        :profile => 'http://samples.ogp.me/390580850990722'
      ) 

    rescue Exception => exc
   # logger.error "Failed to publish review #{review.id} to facebook #{user.facebook_auth}"
     logger.error "Facebook error msg: #{exc.message}"
end
```

It gives me Error **Facebook error msg: undefined method `og_action!' for #** If I do this with curl commands it working fine. I am using fb_graph (2.4.20) and also read about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694334/rails-3-and-publishing-actions-with-fb-graph-gem). Is there any way to solve this problem

Need Help... Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, you aren't setting up the "me" correctly.

https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/wiki/OpenGraph